# Unable to scroll recyclerview when items are added dynamically

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, dynamic-content

Am using recycler view to show a list of data. The data is dynamic (fields are not fixed), so am using linearlayout inside recyclerview item and inflate into it according to response from server. The problem i face is,even though the content is huge, recyclerview stops at screen size and is not scrollable. Tried using relativelayout instead of linear layout as container, but no effect. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/requestIdTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_7"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastActivityTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/requestIdTextView"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_2"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Container to add dynamic elements-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamicSlotDetailsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your root `LinearLayout` hight should be **`wrap_content`**

Comment: @NileshRathod That's correct. How could i miss that!
Thank you (: